# How Swift Vars automatically convert to My Any Type

Tags: swift

I was doing some research on AnyXXX struct like AnyHashable, then I write a similar container named MyAnyHashable.

There's some issues

when I using the original AnyHashalbe is Swift, it works fine:

```
func usingAppleAnyHashable() {
    var dict = Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>()
    
    // using literal as key always works
    dict[1] = 1
    dict["efg"] = "efg_value"
    
    // using some var as key still works
    let any1 = 100
    let any2 = "abc"
    dict[any1] = 100
    dict[any2] = "abc_value"
    
    print(dict)
}
```

it can automatically convert Int's var into AnyHashable, what a Magic!

```
let any1 = 100
let any2 = "abc"
dict[any1] = 100
dict[any2] = "abc_value"
```

Then, I using MyAnyHashable as the Key's Type

```
func usingMyAnyHashable() {
    var dict = Dictionary<MyAnyHashable, Any>()
    
    // using literal as key always works
    dict[1] = 1
    dict["efg"] = "efg_value"
    
    // it show errors: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'MyAnyHashable'...
    let any1 = 100
    let any2 = "abc"
    dict[any1] = 100
    dict[any2] = "abc_value"
    
    print(dict)
}
```

I must write like this to manually create a MyAnyHashable instance

```
dict[MyAnyHashable(any1)] = 100
```

- What is the Magic in Apple's AnyHashable?
- How to make it automatically convert non-Literal var into MyAnyHashable?

Here is MyAnyHashable implementation, I even wrote a ExpressibleByXXXXLiteral which can automatically transform literalType to MyAnyHashable.

```
struct MyAnyHashable : Hashable, Equatable {
    private let baseHash: Int
    private let base: Any
    init<H: Hashable>(_ base: H) {
        self.base = base
        self.baseHash = base.hashValue
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.baseHash)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: MyAnyHashable, rhs: MyAnyHashable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}

extension MyAnyHashable : ExpressibleByStringLiteral, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    
    typealias StringLiteralType = String
    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
    
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int
    init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
    
    typealias FloatLiteralType = Float
    init(floatLiteral value: FloatLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

screenshots

[image: issues]

Comment: Have you seen the [source code of Apple's AnyHashable](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/AnyHashable.swift)?

Comment: I _think_ the behaviour of implicitly converting non-literals to `AnyHashable` is hardcoded into the compiler. You can't make your own type that works the same way unless you fork the compiler.

Comment: the greatest learning from your exercise should be that if you type everything `Any` you miss out on swifts fantastic type system.

Comment: @Sweeper it seems really hardcoded in compiler